# Get average order price

Tags: magento-1.9, orders

I need to get the average order price of a customer in M1.

Getting the totals:

```
$customer = $this->getCustomer();

    $customerTotals = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/sale_collection')
     ->setOrderStateFilter(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_CANCELED, true)
     ->setCustomerFilter($customer)
     ->load()
     ->getTotals();
```

Output:

```
[_data:protected] => Array
        (
            [lifetime] => 6
            [base_lifetime] => 6
            [base_avgsale] => 6
            [num_orders] => 1
            [avgsale] => 6
        )
```

I know I can get:

`lifetime` like- `$customerTotals->getLifetime()` and
`num_orders` like - `$customerTotals->getNumOrders()`

**but how do I get `avgsale`?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quite simply :

```
$customerTotals->getData('avgsale');
```

or

```
$customerTotals->getAvgsale();
```